# How do I use squid as default gateway

Tags: squid, http-proxy, centos6.5

I have installed CentOS 6.5

my default gateway in my infrastructure is 192.168.3.1 (which is firewall IP)

I wanted to change it to the CentOS server IP So that I can limit the usage of the Internet and monitor the Websites used in my network.

I dont want to setup proxy server setting in browser

Appreciate all :)

Comment: If I use the proxy setting with port 3128 in browser  then its working fine and if I use the proxy server IP as default gateway then the error is below


There is no Internet connection

Your computer is offline.

Comment: Failed to stop Squid :Stopping squid: 2016/06/01 11:57:40| strtokFile: /etc/squid/full_access not found
 Warning: empty ACL: acl full_access src "/etc/squid/full_access"
 strtokFile: /etc/squid/user_two not found
2016/06/01 11:57:40| Warning: empty ACL: acl user_two src "/etc/squid/user_two"
| strtokFile: etc/squid/user_three not found
2016/06/01 11:57:40| Warning: empty ACL: acl User_three src "etc/squid/user_three"
2016/06/01 11:57:40| strtokFile: etc/squid/bad_words_1 not found
2016/06/01 11:57:40| Warning: empty ACL: acl bad_words_1 url_regex "etc/squid/bad_words_1"

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

**First option** use iptables firewall and redirect trafic from port 80 to port 3128.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3128
```

**Second option** configure squid to lisaning port 80 instead 3128

By default, Squid listens on port 3128. If you would like to use a different port, modify

**/etc/squid/squid.conf**

```
http_port 80
```

save

```
service squid restart
```

Comment: Failed to stop Squid :
Stopping squid: 2016/06/01 11:57:40| strtokFile: /etc/squid/full_access not found
2016/06/01 11:57:40| Warning: empty ACL: acl full_access src "/etc/squid/full_access"
 strtokFile: /etc/squid/user_two not found
Warning: empty ACL: acl user_two src "/etc/squid/user_two"
 strtokFile: etc/squid/user_three not found
2016/06/01 11:57:40| Warning: empty ACL: acl User_three src "etc/squid/user_three"
 strtokFile: etc/squid/bad_words_1 not found
2016/06/01 11:57:40| Warning: empty ACL: acl bad_words_1 url_regex "etc/squid/bad_words_1"

Any comment on this?